# SPARQL query involving wikiPageWikiLink not working

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

For some reason, this very simple query isn't working:

```
 PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
 SELECT ?link
 WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anarchism>
        dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink ?link }
```

There's nothing wrong with the syntax since a similar query involving external links works fine:

```
 PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
 SELECT ?link
 WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anarchism>
        dbpedia-owl:wikiPageExternalLink ?link}
```

I've looked on their blog and don't see anything about discontinuing the wikiPageWikiLink category. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As of May 2018, pagelinks are stored in a separate named graph: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50171855/7879193

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see by going to http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anarchism, there is no property called `wikiPageWikiLink`. So there's nothing wrong with your query—it just asks for data that's not there.

Answer (score 4):

DBpedia extracts the [Wikipedia page links](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38#wikipedia-pagelinks) and offers them for download, but does not add them to the public SPARQL endpoint. There are simply too many of them - they would overwhelm the SPARQL server.