# Getting hyperlinks of a Wikipedia page using DBpedia

Tags: hyperlink, sparql, rdf, wikipedia, dbpedia

I have two resources in DBPedia: [dbr:Diabetes_mellitus](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Diabetes_mellitus) and [dbr:Hyperglycemia](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hyperglycemia). In Wikipedia, the corresponding pages are [wikipedia-en:Diabetes_mellitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_mellitus) and [wikipedia-en:Hyperglycemia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperglycemia).

In Wikipedia there is a hyperlink from Diabetes_mellitus page to Hyperglycemia page. But when I try to find the link between the 2 resources in DBpedia, I cannot find it.

I tried to find the link using the following SPARQL query.

```
SELECT ?prop WHERE {  
    { dbr:Diabetes_mellitus ?prop dbr:Hyperglycemia } 
    UNION 
    { dbr:Hyperglycemia ?prop dbr:Diabetes_mellitus } 
}
```

But the answer is null. I get nothing as an answer. 
Is there any way to find a link between the pages in DBpedia?

What I am trying to achieve is to get all the hyperlinks in any Wikipedia page. Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: No, this is not possible. However, this is possible in Wikidata. Option 2 from [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11446/16193) is still available.

Comment: DBpedia -> (mostly) the infoboxes of Wikipedia pages. Besides this, there is a separate dataset, called "page links", which might not have been loaded to the public SPARQL endpoint. See [here](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/downloads-2016-10).

Comment: @StanislavKralin there is a dataset for the Wiki links, see "Page Links" at the [download section](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/downloads-2016-10). A sample can be seen [here](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/preview.php?file=2016-10_sl_core-i18n_sl_en_sl_page_links_en.ttl.bz2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of May 2018, page links are stored in the `<http://dbpedia.org/page_links>` named graph.

Your query could be the following one:

```sql
SELECT ?prop
FROM <http://dbpedia.org/page_links> WHERE {
       { dbr:Diabetes_mellitus ?prop dbr:Hyperglycemia }
       UNION
       { dbr:Hyperglycemia ?prop dbr:Diabetes_mellitus }
}
```

[Try it!](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?qtxt=SELECT+%3Fprop%0D%0AFROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fpage_links%3E+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++++++%7B+dbr%3ADiabetes_mellitus+%3Fprop+dbr%3AHyperglycemia+%7D%0D%0A+++++++UNION%0D%0A+++++++%7B+dbr%3AHyperglycemia+%3Fprop+dbr%3ADiabetes_mellitus+%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml)

Using `ASK`:

```sql
ASK
FROM <http://dbpedia.org/page_links> {
dbr:Hyperglycemia dbo:wikiPageWikiLink|^dbo:wikiPageWikiLink dbr:Diabetes_mellitus
}
```

[Try it!](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?qtxt=ASK+FROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fpage_links%3E+%7B%0D%0A+++++dbr%3AHyperglycemia+dbo%3AwikiPageWikiLink%7C%5Edbo%3AwikiPageWikiLink+dbr%3ADiabetes_mellitus%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml)